# How to convert Erlang object structure to Elixir Map?

Tags: erlang, elixir, jiffy

I am using [couchbeam](https://github.com/benoitc/couchbeam) to contact CouchDB from Elixir.

But the lib gives me back old erlang object representation like `{[{"foo", "bar"}]}` and not elixir maps, this was due to the lib using jiffy:decode without `return_maps`, How do I convert this object structure to Elixir maps (and vice versa)?

I found a hackish way to jiffy:encode and jiffy:decode it again with `return_maps` ... But there must be another alternative?

#### Update:

From Hynek's example in erlang, This seems to work:

```
defmodule ToMaps do

  def convert({x}) when is_list(x) do
    Map.new(x, fn {k, v} -> {k, convert(v)} end)
  end

  def convert([head | tail]) do
    [convert(head) | convert(tail)]
  end

  def convert(x) do
    x
  end
end
```

Seems to do the job.

```
iex(1)> ToMaps.convert({[{"foo",[{[{"a",1}]},3]},{"bar","baz"}]})

%{"bar" => "baz", "foo" => [%{"a" => 1}, 3]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know Elixir but in Erlang:

```
-module(to_maps).

-export([to_maps/1]).

to_maps({L}) when is_list(L) ->
    maps:from_list([{K, to_maps(V)} || {K, V} <- L]);
to_maps([H|T]) ->
    [to_maps(H) | to_maps(T)];
to_maps(X) -> X.
```

**Edit**:

Reverse:

```
from_maps(#{} = M) ->
    F = fun(K, V, Acc) -> [{K, from_maps(V)} | Acc] end,
    {maps:fold(F, [], M)};
from_maps([H|T]) ->
    [from_maps(H) | from_maps(T)];
from_maps(X) -> X.
```

I would not recommend it but It can be even one function:

```
convert({L}) when is_list(L) ->
    maps:from_list([{K, convert(V)} || {K, V} <- L]);
convert(#{} = M) ->
    F = fun(K, V, Acc) -> [{K, convert(V)} | Acc] end,
    {maps:fold(F, [], M)};
convert([H|T]) ->
    [convert(H) | convert(T)];
convert(X) -> X.
```

Usage:

```
1> jiffy:decode(<<"{\"foo\":[3, {\"a\":1}], \"bar\":\"baz\"}">>).
{[{<<"foo">>,[3,{[{<<"a">>,1}]}]},{<<"bar">>,<<"baz">>}]}
2> to_maps:to_maps(v(-1)).
#{<<"bar">> => <<"baz">>,<<"foo">> => [3,#{<<"a">> => 1}]}
3> to_maps:from_maps(v(-1)).
{[{<<"foo">>,[3,{[{<<"a">>,1}]}]},{<<"bar">>,<<"baz">>}]}
4> to_maps:convert(v(-1)).
#{<<"bar">> => <<"baz">>,<<"foo">> => [3,#{<<"a">> => 1}]}
5> to_maps:convert(v(-1)).
{[{<<"foo">>,[3,{[{<<"a">>,1}]}]},{<<"bar">>,<<"baz">>}]}
6> to_maps:convert(v(-1)).
#{<<"bar">> => <<"baz">>,<<"foo">> => [3,#{<<"a">> => 1}]}
...
```

Comment: I tried a code in elixir similar to this approach, editing my question.

Comment: @VasuMahesh I think there should be `[convert(head) | convert(tail)]` in your second function clause.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for spotting, also, what will be the other way around? from Maps to this structure? Since in couchbeam, when saving a document, I can't give erlang/elixir maps

Comment: @VasuMahesh: See **Edit** but consider `convert/1` as joke and don't go this way.

Answer (score 0):

I need to see all of your data structure to say for sure but you can use something like this :

```
iex(1)> Enum.into([{"foo", "bar"}], %{})
%{"foo" => "bar"}
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for answering, See Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil's example for the complete data, if you can decode that, this will work for one set, his example seems to cover everything.